# Angular/JS: Click outside element with trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

Need advice. I have a simple popup window which is triggered by... let's say by a button. I need to close this popup by click anywhere else. This is a simple part. I wrote a directive which use $window on 'click' and if target not the same object as directive (or it's child) - then I trigger popup close. But my problem is in the trigger. :) Trigger is outside of popup and when I click trigger it sets **popup.show = true**, but right after this it sets **popup.show = false** via click outside.
I can handle this situation, but I want generic way to handle this. Any advice will be most appritiated. I need just a direction, code is not necessary. Thx :)

Comment: Afterall, I've found similar topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210765/click-outside-div-when-div-has-buttons-that-fires-events-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

backdrop: 'static'

backdrop - controls presence of a backdrop. Allowed values: true (default), false (no backdrop), 'static' - backdrop is present but modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window.

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  backdrop: 'static'
})
```

Comment: thx, but it's not Bootstrap modal. It's just <div ng-show="popup.show"></div>

Comment: You want to trigger the model always on so why you not setting value popup.show = true always on trigger the button?